# Email Sendable Data Extension Results

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a use case where a user wants to receive on a daily basis the data in a sendable data extension.. Example, Recipient Name, Recipient Language, etc.. This will be required at the record level (not aggregate data).

I can FTP the results and provide the user with the path but am looking for a way I can email the results making it easy for the user to access the data. The size of the file is expected to be very small.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean as an attachment, or displayed inside the email (HTML table)?

Comment: As an attachment to an email.

Answer (score 1):

If the data extension record count does not exceed 2000 rows, you might want to try using generating a table with Ampscript (See: [AMPScript to fetch values from data extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158858/ampscript-to-fetch-values-from-data-extension))

Should the table be bigger, talk with your Account Executive to have the Attachment feature enabled (most probably it will be something you will need to pay for additionally). When this is enabled you will be able to use the [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) function in AMPscript